# Rails: delete object 10minutes later after created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to `delete` an object certain times later after it is `created`?

I thought it would be something like? But how can I schedule this action?

```
  after_create :destroy_essay

  def destroy_essay
    #  10minutes later
    # self.destroy  
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a perfect job for a background worker. I'd definitely recommend using `Sidekiq` It even provides a way to perform a job after a certain amount of time in the future. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs

```
EssayDestroyer.perform_at(10.minutes.from_now)
```

On your `EssayDestroyer` worker you'd then write the code to execute to destroy the essay that you created.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably write rake task for this, and use cron, or if you are on Heroku, Heroku Scheduler to run it.

Add a scope in model, like `expired`, which returns all items older than 10 minutes, then in rake task do `Essay.expired.destroy_all` and run this task, for example every one minute.

This rake can look like this:

```
namespace :app do
  desc "Remove expired essays"

  task :remove_expired_essays => :environment do
    Essay.expired.destroy_all
  end
end
```

and the scope in your model:

```
scope :expired, -> { where('created_at >= ?', 10.minutes.ago) }
```

Answer (score 0):

@methyl I think a correct scope would be `scope :expired, -> { where('created_at <= ?', 10.minutes.ago) }`, wouldn't it?